# Create dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

#### Problem

I get individual dictionaries in each iteration of `for` loop, but when the second iteration runs, instead of adding the second dictionary to the first, it replaces the second dictionary over the first dictionary.

```
class Nation:
    def __init__(self, short_name, long_name, iso_code, iso_short, iso_long, capital):
        self.short_name = short_name
        self.long_name = long_name
        self.iso_code = iso_code
        self.iso_short = iso_short
        self.iso_long = iso_long
        self.capital = capital

def to_dictionaries(z):
    a = {}
    sD = {}
    for i in range(len(z)):
        sD["long_name"] = z[i].long_name
        sD["iso_code"] = z[i].iso_code
        sD["iso_short"] = z[i].iso_short
        sD["iso_long"] = z[i].iso_long
        sD["capital"] = z[i].capital
        a.update(sD)
    return a

new_nation_1 = Nation("Albania", "Republic of Albania", 8, "AL", "ALB", "Tirana")
new_nation_2 = Nation("Angola", "Republic of Angola", 24, "AO", "AGO", "Luanda")
nation_list = [new_nation_1, new_nation_2]
print(to_dictionaries(nation_list))
```

#### Desired output:

```
 {"Albania": {"long_name": "Republic of Albania", "iso_code": 8, "iso_short": "AL", "iso_long": "ALB", "capital": "Tirana"},
    "Angola": {"long_name": "Republic of Angola", "iso_code": 24, "iso_short": "AO", "iso_long": "AGO", "capital": "Luanda"}}
```

#### Actual output:

```
{'long_name': 'Republic of Angola', 'iso_code': 24, 'iso_short': 'AO', 'iso_long': 'AGO', 'capital': 'Luanda'}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
a.update(sD)
```

to

```
a[z[i].short_name] = sD
```

Because you need to use the `short_name` as a key.

Another suggestion is put `sD = {}` in the `for` block. So would like:

```
def to_dictionaries(z):
    a = {}
    for i in range(len(z)):
        sD = {}
        sD["long_name"] = z[i].long_name
        sD["iso_code"] = z[i].iso_code
        sD["iso_short"] = z[i].iso_short
        sD["iso_long"] = z[i].iso_long
        sD["capital"] = z[i].capital
        a[z[i].short_name] = sD
    return a
```

Comment: Additionally, the OP never uses index `i`, so a `for nation in z` and replacing `z[i]` with `nation` would be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

class Nation:

    def __init__(self, short_name, long_name, iso_code, iso_short, iso_long, capital):
        self.short_name = short_name
        self.long_name = long_name
        self.iso_code = iso_code
        self.iso_short = iso_short
        self.iso_long = iso_long
        self.capital = capital

nations = [
    Nation('Albania', 'Republic of Albania', 8, 'AL', 'ALB', 'Tirana'),
    Nation('Angola', 'Republic of Angola', 24, 'AO', 'AGO', 'Luanda'),
]

d = {n.short_name : dict(n.__dict__) for n in nations}
print(json.dumps(d, indent = 4))
```

Comment: Also, should remove the short name from n.__dict__

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar It's true that removing `short_name` would better match the OP's literal question, but there is rarely benefit to doing so -- at least in my experience. If you have a dict-of-dictified-objects, it's almost always handier and more flexible across a wide variety of programming situations to retain all attributes of interest inside the values -- even if it means that the outer keys will indeed duplicate one piece of information among the inner dicts.

Answer (score 0):

@FMc answer is great and we can remove the short_name by **pop**.

```
import json

class Nation:

    def __init__(self, short_name, long_name, iso_code, iso_short, iso_long, capital):
        self.short_name = short_name
        self.long_name = long_name
        self.iso_code = iso_code
        self.iso_short = iso_short
        self.iso_long = iso_long
        self.capital = capital

nations = [
    Nation('Albania', 'Republic of Albania', 8, 'AL', 'ALB', 'Tirana'),
    Nation('Angola', 'Republic of Angola', 24, 'AO', 'AGO', 'Luanda'),
]
nations = [dict(n.__dict__) for n in nations]
# pop will remove short_name from n and returns it's value.
d = {n.pop('short_name') : n for n in nations}
print(json.dumps(d, indent = 4))
```